# How to turn static pages in HTML or PSD into nodejs app?

Tags: node.js

I am wondering if there are easy tutorials or examples online that can guide me how to make static pages in HTML or from PSD into nodejs app? I read nodejs or its documentation and it is a bit overwhelming for me to understand.

Is it even possible to turn static pages into nodejs app?

Comment: If you just want to serve static web pages, you could use http://expressjs.com/

Comment: @Sirko - wow but unfortunately i am required to work with nodejs. is there any way?

Comment: express.js is a framework/library for nodejs. See the [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) for a hello world application.

Comment: `NodeJS` is server side language,like PHP and Rails

Comment: So all html go into views? rails use mvc so i know that html goes into view, but not sure about nodejs

Comment: you can use your html as views and use Expressjs Framework [ http://expressjs.com/ ] with NodeJs to create dynamic site.Online tutorials: [ http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-express--net-33367 ]
yes @joe, html just views in `Nodejs`